# How do you add rician noise to an image?

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, noise, image-preprocessing

This is what I have tried so far, this is the output:

```
from scipy.stats import rice

rice.rvs(img)
```

Answer (score 2):

[Rician noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice_distribution) can most easily be generated by taking the magnitude of a bivariate normal distribution.

```py
import numpy as np

# Parameters of Rician noise
v = 8
s = 5
N = 100  # how many samples

noise = np.random.normal(scale=s, size=(N, 2)) + [[v,0]]
noise = np.linalg.norm(noise, axis=1)
```

To add this noise to an image `img`, set `N = img.size`, generate the noise, and then

```py
img += noise.reshape(img.shape)
```